# Training a model with LUIS using Phrase List Features with overlapping words

Tags: nlp, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a word for example `ABC SSS`. I need this to be recognised as one entity. At the same time this `ABC SSS` phrase precedes a lot of other words that need to be recognised as one entity which are not interchangeable. For example `ABC SSS word`. How can I train LUIS to be able to do this. I tried `ABC SSS` as a phrase feature but then LUIS doesn't recognise `ABC SSS word` as an entity. Currently, I marked `ABC SSS` as a feature phrase and `word` as a separate feature phrase. This is not ideal. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to create composite entities, not use phrase lists for this.

Here's a screenshot of the entities creation page on LUIS. I've created three simple entities and one composite entity which takes the other three entities:

[image: Entities]

Here are some snippets from a response I got from LUIS on a query. This first bit indicates the actual query and matched intent.

```
"query": "order large pepperoni pizza",
"topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "OrderPizza",
    "score": 0.9999995
},
```

Under the entities list you'll find your simple *and* composite entities together, like the following.

```
{
    "entity": "large",
    "type": "PizzaSize",
    "startIndex": 6,
    "endIndex": 10,
    "score": 0.9186653
},
{
    "entity": "large",
    "type": "Pizza", // This is the composite entity!
    "startIndex": 6,
    "endIndex": 10,
    "score": 0.940835536
}
```

And here is the list for composite entities:

```
"compositeEntities": [
    {
      "parentType": "Pizza",
      "value": "large",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "PizzaSize",
          "value": "large"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "parentType": "Pizza",
      "value": "pepperoni",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "PizzaTopping",
          "value": "pepperoni"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "parentType": "Pizza",
      "value": "pizza",
      "children": []
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm currently trying out this solution. Thanks for the clarity in the example. can I also check, in my case, it's more like I need my model to recognise entities made of more than one word. Example: San Diego needs to be recognised a city (instead of just reading san or diego separately). At the same time, I have another phrase like "san diego pizza" which needs to be recognised as a value of a single entity. For "san diego" phrase list works just fine. But once I add "san diego pizza" neither phrases gets detected. Is your suggestion still applicable?

Comment: Sorry I missed this! This method is still applicable; that it's not working for you is odd... Is this still an issue for you? If you have an example of the response, could you edit your original question to include it?

Answer (score 0):

Composite Entities are ideal for this case:

Set "ABC SSS" as an entity 1, but then tag "ABC SSS" plus those other words into a composite entity 2. This should be enough to both capture "ABC SSS" as entity 1 and the whole sentence as entity 2 in the case those other phrases appear.

Also, you can also tag those other words as Entities by themselves if you want to capture them while you are on it.